# JTree drop index between nodes

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtree

I've implemented drag and drop in my JTree and it works, but I find this to be a bit confusing. In the picture, I'm showing how the drop location between `item4` and `item5` can vary depending on how far down between the nodes you are. I'm guessing this is because the row boundaries for `item4` and `item5` meet in the middle between them, and depending on which side you are on, you are actually in a different row.

From a user perspective, I think this is not natural. I would think that if I dropped above a node, the drop would occur above it. If I dropped below the node, the drop would occur below it. Is there a way to configure that sort of behavior?

[image]

EDIT: Adding code to show how to get drop location

```
    DropLocation dropLoc = support.getDropLocation();
    Point dropPoint = dropLoc.getDropPoint();
    tree.getTree().getPathForLocation(dropPoint.x, dropPoint.y);
```

Note that `support` is a `TransferSupport` object

EDIT 2: I seemed to have solved this problem by checking if the drop point is above or below the halfway point of the node. Then I can tell if the drop was above or below which node.

Comment: Could you show us the code that selects where to drop a node?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid posting the entire drag/drop code since it is a fair amount of swing code that can be tedious to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have sort out of the answer, but since i have sort out the code, thinking still worth to post it.

```
        public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent dtde)
        {
            Point dropPoint = dtde.getLocation();
            TreePath path = tree.getPathForLocation(dropPoint.x, dropPoint.y);
            Rectangle pathBounds = tree.getPathBounds(path);
            Rectangle topHalf = new Rectangle(pathBounds.x, pathBounds.y, pathBounds.width, pathBounds.height / 2);
            if (topHalf.contains(dropPoint))
            {
                System.out.println("top half");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("bottom half");
            }
         }
```